# Is Stack Overflow the right place to ask for help finding a web article?

Tags: discussion

2 years back, I had seen an article on the Internet.

You could draw lines on that page with mouse click and drag. Also,If some other visitor is online, you could also see what he was drawing.Not sure whether it was related to Node.js
I have googled a lot since past 2 days, in vain

So,If tag Node.js and ask it... I see a good chance of finding that article. Should I proceed.Or would I get downvotes coz it might not be correct place.

I know this is programming site.So is it fine to ask anything related to programming or only related to coding related work of programming. I don't think there should be an issue with the former.

Answer (score 10):

The question is for an off-site resource.

That type of question is pretty much off-topic across the Stack Exchange network.

Asking for a website, however related to programming that site may be, is not a programming question.

Comment: You can however pop into chat and ask if someone knows of such material or references.